# Why is Copy constructor called even when we have Move constructor and working with R-value?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

*Why is Copy constructor making a Deep-copy of 10 here? I tried to debug the code too in-order to understand but to no avail. Please dear programming lords of stack-overflow help this peasent.*

**My Question basically is :**

*Why is this program making a Deep copy at all? Isn't the very use of Move semantic to eliminate making copies?*

*Second Question - Lets suppose it is making copy of 10 for **x** reason then why isn't it making deep copy for 20?*

**Here is the code :**

```
// C++ program with declaring the
// move constructor
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Move Class
class Move {
private:
    // Declare the raw pointer as
    // the data member of class
    int* data;

public:

    // Constructor
    Move(int d)
    {
        // Declare object in the heap
        data = new int;
        *data = d;
        cout << "Constructor is called for "
            << d << endl;
    };

    // Copy Constructor
    Move(const Move& source)
        : Move{ *source.data }
    {

        // Copying the data by making
        // deep copy
        cout << "Copy Constructor is called -"
            << "Deep copy for "
            << *source.data
            << endl;
    }

    // Move Constructor
    Move(Move&& source)
        : data{ source.data }
    {

        cout << "Move Constructor for "
            << *source.data << endl;
        source.data = nullptr;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Move()
    {
        if (data != nullptr)

            // If pointer is not pointing
            // to nullptr
            cout << "Destructor is called for "
                << *data << endl;
        else

            // If pointer is pointing
            // to nullptr
            cout << "Destructor is called"
                << " for nullptr "
                << endl;

        // Free up the memory assigned to
        // The data member of the object
        delete data;
    }
};

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    // Vector of Move Class
    vector<Move> vec;

    // Inserting Object of Move Class
    vec.push_back(Move{ 10 });
    vec.push_back(Move{ 20 });
    return 0;
}
```

**Output of the program is :**

```
Constructor is called for 10
Move Constructor for 10
Destructor is called for nullptr 
Constructor is called for 20
Move Constructor for 20
Constructor is called for 10
Copy Constructor is called -Deep copy for 10
Destructor is called for 10
Destructor is called for nullptr 
Destructor is called for 10
Destructor is called for 20
```

Comment: Your move constructor is not marked with `noexcept`, `std::vector` cannot use it when it reallocates data. I'll try to find a duplicate question about that.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen When does std::vector need to reallocate data? And if that is a problem then why 20 is not reallocated? Thanks.

Comment: @LearningNoob123 Vector allocates some extra memory for future elements, so that `push_back()` can be amortized constant complexity intead of linear. C++ standard does not say how much it should allocate, but some known standard libraries use powers of 2 - it first allocates memory for 1, then for 2, then 4 etc. If you `push_back()` and there is no more this extra memory left - reallocation happens. In this case, there was `capacity()` of 1 after inserting 10, so the next `push_back` triggers reallocation. There is no more `push_back` after inserting 20, so no more reallocations happen.

Comment: I assume that the use of `new` here was just to have a reason to show the move constructor. I still want to remind any readers that are new to c++, that using `new`/`delete` is bad practice. By using `std::unique_ptr` and "the rule of 0", the compiler should in this case have done the right thing.

Comment: The comment from @user2807083 is just completely wrong. `emplace_back` will make absolutely no difference here. Both emplace_back and push_back will call the move constructor when called with an rvalue.